# String handling in C language for Espressif ESP-IDF

Tags: c, arrays, string

The following function call is derived from espressif ESP-IDF and will send an mqtt message  (event->data) with length event->data_len).

`esp_mqtt_client_publish(mqtt_client, CONFIG_EXAMPLE_PUBLISH_TOPIC, event->data , event->data_len, 1, 0);`

Instead, if event->data I want to extend this character array by some additional characters like "I got [event->data] !" and send this message by the function shown above.

I know, there are many ways how to achieve this, but every solution I found, results in a couple of lines that are ridiculous complicated in my eyes.

```
    //Buffer to hold event->data as a string with \0 termination
    char *bufData = calloc(event->data_len + 1, sizeof(char));
    snprintf(bufData, event->data_len + 1, "%s", event->data); // get a zero ended string from event->data

    //Additional Buffer to hold complete String
    int mqttStringBufSize = strlen(bufData) + 30;
    char *mqttStringBuf = calloc(mqttStringBufSize, sizeof(char));
    snprintf(mqttStringBuf, mqttStringBufSize, "I received [%s]", bufData);

    esp_mqtt_client_publish(mqtt_client, CONFIG_EXAMPLE_PUBLISH_TOPIC,
            mqttStringBuf, strlen(mqttStringBuf), 1, 0);

    free(bufData);
    free(mqttStringBuf);
```

So I am looking for a clean solution to this problem.

Comment: A couple of likes of complicated code isn't necessarily bad if it does the job, and the complication may be needed.

Comment: not complicated, you'll need to create a new string with whatever you want it to say, then send that instead. I suppose any complication comes from ensuring the new string has enough space.

Comment: Although, IMO, I think you should leave this as-is, and add any desired window dressing to the display on the receiver. Depends on your particular situation, but in general you want to send raw data and let the receivers decide how to present it. The fact this is a `publish` function suggests there could be 1 to many subscribers, and each subscriber may want to do something different with the raw data (including not display it at all). Surrounding the raw data with eye candy in the publisher adds unnecessary complication to each subscriber to parse out the raw data.

Comment: Meanwhile I edited my original question to show the solution I use.